# Prove that integration is continuous under weak star topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(0,1)$ be the Borel sigma algebra on $(0,1)$ and $m$ be the Lebesgue measure. Consider $L^\infty((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),m)$ equipped with weak-star topology and $B=\{f\in L^\infty(0,1):0\le f\le 1\}$.

Let $g\in L^1(0,1)$ and $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. By the definition of weak star topology, it is clear that the mapping $f\mapsto\int_0^1fgdx$ is continuous in $B$.

However, I want to know under what conditions can we conclude that $f\mapsto\int_0^1\phi(f)dx$ is also continuous in B?

Comment: You need that $\phi$ is an affine function.

Comment: Is it possible to relax the condition that $\phi$ is merely the Legendre transform of a smooth convex function, which is exactly what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\phi$ is not affine. Then, there are $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ with
$$
\phi(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \ne \lambda \phi(x) + (1-\lambda) \phi(y).$$

It is well known that there exists a sequence $(f_n) \subset B$ with the properties
$$ f_n(t) \in \{ x , y \} \quad\text{f.a.a. } t \in (0,1),$$
$$m(\{t \in (0,1) \mid f_n(t) = x\}) = \lambda$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N$
and
$f_n \rightharpoonup^* f$, where $f \equiv \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$.

Thus,
$$
\int_0^1 \phi(f(t)) \,\mathrm dt = \lambda \phi(x) + (1-\lambda) \phi(y),
$$
but
$$
\int_0^1 \phi(f(t)) \,  \mathrm dt = \phi(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y).$$

In the case that $\phi$ is convex and lower semicontinuous, it might be possible to show that
$$
f \mapsto \int_0^1 \phi(f(t)) \mathrm dt$$
is sequentially weak* lower semicontinuous.